# Setting Layout Height to Wrapcontent to dynamically created textview

Tags: android, textview

I have created LinearLayout programatically as

```
LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
```

and TextView as `TextView et = new TextView(getContext());`

i wanted textviews layout height to be wrapcontent so i did this

```
et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and then i add Textview et to LinearLayout as

```
wrapper.addView(et);
```

but when i set LayoutParams as above my textview dissapears and doesn't show in UI.
If I remove it by default Textview takes height as MATCHPARENT.

How can i set textviews layoutheight to `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Comment: have you try by setting text in it.

Comment: i think it disappears because it has nothing to show.

Comment: I have set text ,if i dont set layoutparams for textview my text is visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
LinearLayout first_lay = new LinearLayout(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_icon = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

first_lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
first_lay.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams tests = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
text1.setLayoutParams(tests);
text1.setText("Text");
text1.setTextSize(18);

first_lay.addView(text1);
```

Comment: @Mario did you using `setContentView(first_lay)` or adding `first_lay` into some other xml view

Answer (score 0):

also have to add that parent linear layout into the main contentlayout parent i.e it all be visible in side activity view

```
  LinearLayout child_insidenew_layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                        child_insidenew_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams child_inside_paramsnew = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        child_insidenew_layout.setLayoutParams(child_inside_paramsnew);
  child_insidenew_layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                        child_insidenew_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout_selector);
TextView textrootname = new TextView(getActivity());
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams TextView_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  textrootname.setText("here is ur text");
  textrootname.setSingleLine(true);
  textrootname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  textrootname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  textrootname.setTextSize(15);
  child_insidenew_layout.addView(textrootname, TextView_params);
```

Comment: dude have u set any setcontentview in activity :)